# Executing a mix of single-row NHibernate Save's and HQL deletes with subselect in a single database call

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, .net-4.0

I'm using NHibernate 3.2.0.4000, SQL Server 2012, C# .NET 4.0 MVC.

I have an NHibernate session in which a class A object is `Save`'d and an HQL `delete` statement is executed against a class B object.

The DEBUG level logging showed...

> DEBUG NHibernate.SQL delete from MyDb.MySchema.ClassB ...
>   DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher ExecuteNonQuery took 5 ms
>   DEBUG NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction Start Commit
>   DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher Adding to batch:INSERT INTO MyDb.MySchema.ClassA ...
>   DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher ExecuteBatch for 1 statements took 6 ms

The SQL Profiler shows the 2 statements as being part of 2 separate remote procedure calls `RPC:Completed` events.

The above log reference to a batch with 1 statement and the profiler data seem to indicate that the 2 statements are being executed in two separate database calls. How can these 2 statements be combined into a single database call, just like is done when using Future and FutureValue with select statements?

Some extra details that might help are:

```
//The NHibernate Insert code  
ClassADao.Save(new ClassA());  

//The HQL delete code
session.CreateQuery  
(  
    "delete from Solution.Project.Classes.ClassB as classB " +  
    "where exists ( " +  
        "from Solution.Project.Classes.ClassC as classC " +  
        "where classC.classD_FK.Id = :classD_FK_Id_One " +  
        "and classC = classB.classC_FK " +  
        "and classB.classD_FK.Id = :classD_FK_Id_Two " +  
    ") "  
)  
.SetInt32("classD_FK_Id_One", Id1)  
.SetInt32("classD_FK_Id_Two", Id2)  
.ExecuteUpdate();  

//The DEBUG level logged translation of the above HQL delete statement
delete from MyDb.MySchema.CLASSB  
where exists (  
    select CLASSC1_.id  
    from MyDb.MySchema.CLASSC CLASSC1_  
    where CLASSC1_.classd_id = @p0  
    and classc_id = MyDb.MySchema.CLASSB.classc_id  
    and MyDb.MySchema.CLASSB.classd_id = @p1  
);  

//and the fact that I'm using adonet.batch_size value of 5.`
```

Thanks in advance for all attempts to help.

Answer (score 0):

`adonet.batch_size` doesn't create single `sp_executesql` commands. This wouldn't be possible, because `sp_executesql` is created by NHibernate, while the ado.net batch behind the scenes.

In fact, you do not see the ado.net batches with the SQL Profiler. It creates a single server call with multiple commands, which are all seen separately with the Profiler.

Comment: Ok. I'm having trouble to confirm if that's true. I assumed a single ADO batch meant a single db call, correct? Because in profiler, although I cannot see an ADO batch, I can see that each statement is generating a separate and distinct event of the type RPC:Completed, (RPC -> remote procedure call), and I had assumed, wrongly?, that 2 distinct RPC:Completed events means they were 2 distinct database calls, and therefore more than 1 ADO batch.

Comment: It's probably not taking Flush (before the query) and the query into one batch.